# Spark date parsing

Tags: datetime, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am parsing some dates in this format: `2009-01-23 18:15:05` using the following function

```
  def loadTransactions (sqlContext: SQLContext, path: String): DataFrame = {
    val rowRdd = sqlContext.sparkContext.textFile(path).map { line =>
      val tokens = line.split(',')
      val dt = new DateTime(tokens(0))
      Row(new Timestamp(dt.getMillis))
    }
    val fields = Seq(
      StructField("timestamp", TimestampType, true)
    )
    val schema = StructType(fields)
    sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd, schema)
  }
```

Spark is throwing an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2009-01-23 18:15:05" is malformed at " 18:15:05" at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.doParseMillis
```

I presume that it is due to the fact that the milliseconds are missing

Comment: Which version of spark you are using ?

Comment: I am using Spark 1.5.2

Comment: The ISO 8601 has a T between the date and time part. The value you pass isn't a standard ISO datetime value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using jodatime, you can use the following method

```
    def loadTransactions (sqlContext: SQLContext, path: String): DataFrame = {
    val rowRdd = sqlContext.sparkContext.textFile(path).map { line =>
      val tokens = line.split(',')
      Row(getTimestamp(tokens(0)))
    }
    val fields = Seq(
      StructField("timestamp", TimestampType, true)
    )
    val schema = StructType(fields)
    sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd, schema)
  }
```

Use the following function to convert to timestamp.

```
  def getTimestamp(x:String) :java.sql.Timestamp = {
    val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    if (x.toString() == "")
      return null
    else {

      val d = format.parse(x.toString());
      val t = new Timestamp(d.getTime());
      return t
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

How about something like this?

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_extract

def loadTransactions (sqlContext: SQLContext, path: String): DataFrame = {
  sqlContext.sparkContext.textFile(path).toDF("text").select(
    regexp_extract($"text", "^(.*?),", 1).cast("timestamp").alias("timestamp"))
}
```