# Spark DataSet date time parsing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

How should I properly perform date time parsing with spark 2.0 dataset API?

There are lots of samples for data frame / RDD like

- [Spark date parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608304/spark-date-parsing)
- [Better way to convert a string field into timestamp in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844144/better-way-to-convert-a-string-field-into-timestamp-in-spark)
- [How to change the column type from String to Date in DataFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36948012/how-to-change-the-column-type-from-string-to-date-in-dataframes)

A class like

```
case class MyClass(myField:java.sql.Datetime)

val mynewDf = spark.read
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("charset", "UTF-8")
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .csv("pathToFile.csv")
    .as[MyClass]
```

Is not enough to cast the type.
How should I perform this properly using the data set API?

## edit

loading the data works. Eg. a `print schema` shows `myDateFiled: timestamp (nullable = true)`
But a myDf.show results in a

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:143)
```

which lead me to believe that my parsing of the dates was incorrect. How can this be?

Comment: Sorry, it is not really clear to me what you're trying to achieve here and what your problem is. Could you show us a sample of the input file and detail a bit your question ?

Comment: Probably should rephrase: how to perform an explicit cast for datasets.

Comment: @cheseaux please also see the clarification in the latest edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A correct representation of a timestamp is `java.sql.Timestamp`  so class should be defined as

```
case class MyClass(myField: java.sql.Timestamp)
```

with coressponding data:

```
myField
"2016-01-01 00:00:03"
```

If this conditions are satisfied all you have to do is to provide schema:

```
spark.read
  .options(Map("header" -> "true"))
  .schema(StructType(Seq(StructField("myField", TimestampType, false))))
  .csv(...)
  .as[MyClass]
```

It is possible to provide alternative date format using `dateFormat` with [`SimpleDateFormat` string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Schema definition can be replaced with type casting before `.as[MyClass]`:

```
spark.read
  .options(Map("header" -> "true"))
  .csv(...)
  .withColumn("myField", $"myField".cast("timestamp"))
  .as[MyClass]
```

For `DateType` use `java.sql.Date`.